# List Slicing in Python Without Using Built-In Function?

Tags: python, list, slice

I'm very new to programming and am currently stuck on a practice problem involving list slicing without using the built-in function, so the idea is that you create your own slice function to be called upon by the user. Below is the question and following that is my attempt to solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Python provides slicing functionality for lists, but for this question, you will implement your own function capable of producing list slices (note: you cannot use the slicing operator in your solution). The function should be called slice and take the following three inputs in this specific order:

1. A list, source, which the slice will be created from. This list cannot be modified by your function.
2. A positive integer, start, representing the starting index of the slice you will create. If this value is not in the range [0, len(list)-1], your function should return an empty list.
3. A positive integer, end, representing the ending index of the slice you will create. If this value is not in the range [start, len(list)-1], your function should return an empty list.
   If the parameter values are acceptable, your function will return a list that contains the items from source beginning at the index start and ending at the index end (inclusive). This is different from the Python slice operator, as the item at the index end is also included in the new list.

## Examples:

```
mylist = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]  
slice(mylist, 0, 9) should be ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"] slice(mylist, 3, 4) should be ["D", "E"]  
slice(mylist, 4, 3) should be [ ]  
slice(mylist, 3, 8) should be ["D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]  
slice(mylist, 4, 4) should be ["E" ]
```

## My code:

```
source=int(input("Enter a list: "))  
start=int(input("Enter the starting digit: "))  
end=int(input("Enter the ending digit: "))  
  
def slice(source,start,end):  
        if start is not [0, len(source)-1]:
            print()  
        elif end is not [start, len(source)-1]:  
            print()  
    source.append(0,start)  
    source.append(len(source),end)  
  
slice[]
```

Comment: Nice attempt. What is your question?

Comment: @Mitch I do not see what is nice about this attempt.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks :p the question is above the examples.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's constructive and kind thank you

Comment: @kleenexbox, what happens if it is out of index?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf it's supposed to return an empty list if out of index.

Comment: @kleenexbox Ok, let's start from the top. How are you planning on reading a list with this: `source=int(input("Enter a list: "))`. Break your problems into smaller ones. *Pass a list* could be one of those

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I figured the user needed to input the list? Not sure what you mean

Comment: add `print(source)` below your first line and run it. tell me if it does what you expected

Comment: ok now line 11   source.append(0,start) keeps returing IndentationError that I can't seem to fix @Ev.Kounis

Comment: The first `if` within your function sets the indentation level which is then ignored by `source.append(0,start)`...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself, thanks for trying to help without being condescending @lmiguelvargasf I really appreciate it.

```
start = int(input(" Enter the starting index of the slice you will create: "))
end = int(input("Enter the ending index of the slice you will create:  "))
def slice(source, start, end):
    myList = []
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        if start in range(0, len(source)) and end in range(start,     len(source)):
        myList.append(source[i])
return myList

myList = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'] #This is the source
print(slice(myList,start,end))
```